# How do I connect onedrive with my onedrive profile

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive

My Windows 8.1 computer came pre-installed with OneDrive. It is syncing to something. I created a Microsoft account (profile) on their web site. After an hour of searching, I can't figure out how to connect the two things. I'm rather confused. If I have no profile connected to OneDrive, what does it sync to?

Comment: Onedrive uses a microsoft account. So long as you're using the same account you'll see the same files any place you access Onedrive.

Comment: This question does not really make sense, OneDrive only syncs with the connected Microsoft Account, so the creation of a second account does not make sense

Comment: Ok, as windows 8.1 does not really seem to make a difference between user accounts and windows profiles this was an oversight of me

but it is still hard as hell to access the online profile if you intended to never use the microsoft profile and just entered a random email adress

and to be honest microsoft user accounts are pretty useless, 
I created probably 6 so far and all were only 1 time uses

Answer (score 0):

In order to sync you OneDrive files to the Microsoft servers, you have to create a profile with Microsoft. It sounds like you already have 6 different accounts. You must select one of them and enter the login and password to your OneDrive program. If you are unsure which account is linked to OneDrive, you must first unlink then enter your login and password.

- To unlink, right-click on OneDrive system tray icon
- Select Settings
- Unlink

[image: Settings]

[image]